# Encrypt folder and open with java application

Tags: java, swing, io, jfilechooser, jce

My java application stores data in a folder at user home directory.
How can i encrypt that folder but access the encrypted folder with an application?

I tried to encrypt the folder with java, (Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)), but cannot access this folder from within my application without decrypting it.

I need the user to have no access to this folder, only within my application.

Comment: You will not be able to access an encrypted folder without decrypting it. You might want to do that in a temporary folder, so that you have an unencrypted copy for use in your application, leaving the original folder encrypted.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly, but if you want encrypted files, that can only be read by your application - then all you need is a method that can encrypt data, a method to decrypt it again and some key (where ever you want to store that savely). Then all your application has to do is encrypt the data before writing it to a file and decrypt it again, when needed. Key and everything else about the encryption should be handled in a way your user can't see. Additionally you can hide the files in the system (in unix, prefix the file name with a `.`) and give them "encrpyted" names.

Comment: Why can't you encrypt the files themselves rather than the 'folder'? You can even obfuscate the filenames if they give away what they are storing (albeit encrypted) if you also care about that.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This is going to be a bit of an unorthodox answer, and might not be exactly what the OP is looking for.*

One possible solution is to zip the files in your folder, and then encrypt the zip file. 
Reading its contents will be slower of course, but is perfectly feasible with Java's NIO Zip File system provider. You will need to decrypt it back so that it is back to zip format.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Not sure how frequently the files will change by the application, and how feasible it is to update the zip file and re-encrypt it for what is needed.